# Customer segmentation price list does not work as expected in basket and checkout

Tags: intershop, isml

**The problem**

We have created a customer segment and linked both a customer and a price list to this customer segment. The linked price list defines a special price of $5 for one of the products. This product has a 'default' price of $10.

When I login to the storefront with a user that belongs to customer segment, I see the correct price of $5 on the PDP. However once this product is added to the basket, it shows the 'default' product price of $10 in the minicart and on the cart page. I would expect to see $5 there as well.

**Technical information**

The (correct) price on the PDP is retrieved directly from the `ProductBO` by using the default `ISProductPrice` module which links to the default `ProductPrice.isml`.

```
<ISProductPrice 
    ProductBO="#ProductBO#"
    Currency="#CurrentRequest:Currency#"
    ShowInformationalPrice="true"
    RichSnippetsEnabled="#RichSnippetsEnabled#"
>
```

The (wrong) price on the cart page is retrieved from the `BasketComputedProductLineItemBO` with the following (default ISH) code

```
<isif condition="#PriceDisplayType EQ 'net'#">
    <isprint value="#PLI:SingleBasePriceNet#">
<iselse/>
    <isprint value="#PLI:SingleBasePriceGross#">
</isif>
```

**What I've tried so far**

- Clear cookies/cache to make sure we have a completely new basket
- Made sure the Customer Segmentation Service is enabled (default ISH service).
- Tried all the different methods to fetch a price from the `BasketComputedProductLineItemBO`
- Added a couple of different products to the price list
- Added a couple of different customers to the customer segment
- Ran a search index
- Tried to reproduce the issue on the ISH demo server
- Checked the documentation on customer segmentation from the ISH support page
- Tried to add a customer to the price list directly instead of a customer segment. When doing it this way, everything seems to work as expected.

At this point I'm completely stuck. Any help on how to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Bas! Which version of ish?

Comment: In 7.9 it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Willem, we are on 7.9.0.5 to be exact. I tried to reproduce the issue on the 7.9 demo server but it was working as expected there as well. It's a strange issue since we are using the exact same ISML to retrieve the pricing info as the demo shop. At this point i'm starting to suspect something is wrong with our PLI objects, as for the ProductBOs it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Check this
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/IS-22923

If you search on segment on the support for version 7.9 then you get few bugs. Disable the dynamic segment service because it is buggy. See if that work or else i think you really do have a platform bug here.

Also a good idea to upgrade to the lastest minor version.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I've checked and we really do use the 'Standard Customer Segmentation Service', the demo one is completely disabled. I'm afraid you are correct and we have a platform bug indeed. I will investigate further.